# Slow Auto focus in Camera2

Tags: android-camera2

I am trying to make a custom camera application, the autofocus function works sometimes and sometime it is taking too long time to focus.  I am using the camera as -

```
Camera camera = Camera.open(requestedCameraId);
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    
parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.getWidth(), pictureSize.getHeight());
parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(
        previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MIN_INDEX],
        previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX]);
parameters.setPreviewFormat(IMAGE_FORMAT);
 
if(parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
      }
if(parameters.isAutoExposureLockSupported()){
        parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
      }
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

What changes I need to make to make the auto focus smooth even if the user places the camera steady to analyze multiple images from live camera view?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why the autofocus function works sometimes and sometime it is taking too long time to focus ?